# Switching Between Themes at Runtime

Tags: surveyjs

The documentation says that you can use multiple themes by just including the Javascript files of the theme and the calling `survey.applyTheme()`:

```
<!-- In classic script applications: -->
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/survey-core/defaultV2.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/survey-core/survey.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/survey-core/themes/contrast-dark.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/survey-core/themes/contrast-light.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
<script>
const surveyJson = { ... };
const survey = new Survey.Model(surveyJson);
survey.applyTheme(SurveyTheme.ContrastLight);
</script>
```

The problem is that each Javascript theme file overrides the SurveyTheme object. So in this case,  ContrastLight would be available but ContrastDark wouldn't.

- I check the SurveyTheme object in the browse console and it only had one theme
- I tried changing the order of the JS files to prove that only could be available at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load all the themes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/survey-core/themes/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: The tradeoff here, which is acceptable for my use case, is that index.js is fairly large at 180kb (minified).

Comment: Undortunately you right :-(